# Try alternative html files in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a small VueJS app which is located in index.html. For SEO value I've also started generating a lot of static html files in subfolders. The problem is that Nginx only routes my requests to index.html, and not to these static html files.

I'd like all requests to for instance `mydomain.com/podcast/test-podcast/first-episode.html` to serve `/podcast/test-podcast/first-episode.html`

What directive do I need to add in Nginx to add such a rule?

Here's my conf file:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  index index.html;

  server_name localhost;

  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?q=$uri&$args;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
  }

  location @rewrites {
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html last;
  }

  location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    # Some basic cache-control for static files to be sent to the browser
    expires max;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long work but not impossible; For each page you will need to create a NGinx rules

```
...

location /podcast/test-podcast/first-episode.html {
    root    /usr/share/nginx/html/podcast/test-podcast/
    index   first-episode.html
}

location /blabla/seo-roxx/example.html {
    root    /blabla/seo-roxx/example/
    index   example.html
}

...
```

You may want to rethink you SEO strategie to avoid doing it in NGinx.